# На каком уровне лучше использовать RestTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, rest, resttemplate

У меня есть web-приложение, которое взаимодействует с Spotify API. Для запросов я использую клас RestTemplate. Приведу пример, мне нужной найти топ треков пользователя, я делаю соответствующий запрос в сервисе:
TopTrackService:

```
    @Service
    public class TopTrackService {
    
        private final AuthService authService;
        private final RestTemplate restTemplate;
        private final ObjectMapper mapper;
    
        @Autowired
        public TopTrackService(AuthService authService, RestTemplate restTemplate, ObjectMapper mapper) {
            this.authService = authService;
            this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
            this.mapper = mapper;
        }
    
        private final String url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/top/tracks?limit=10&time_range=";
    
        public void findTopTracks(String term, Model model) throws JsonProcessingException {
                JsonNode currentUserTopTracksJson = mapper.readTree(restTemplate.exchange( url + term, HttpMethod.GET, authService.useToken(), String.class).getBody());
        
                //Top track card
                model.addAttribute("tracks", currentUserTopTracksJson.get("items"));
            }
}
```

А потом внедряю его в контроллер и вызываю там метод:

MainController:

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    private final AuthService authService;
    private final TopTrackService topTrackService;
    private final TopArtistService topArtistService;
    private final UserService userService;
    public final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public MainController(AuthService authService, TopTrackService topTrackService, TopArtistService topArtistService, UserService userService, RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.authService = authService;
        this.topTrackService = topTrackService;
        this.topArtistService = topArtistService;
        this.userService = userService;
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

   

    @GetMapping("/profile")
    public String myProfile(@RequestParam(value = "time_range",defaultValue = "short_term") String time_range, Model model) throws JsonProcessingException, UnauthorizedUserException {
            //Top track Card
            topTrackService.findTopTracks(time_range,model);     
        return "profile";
    }
}
```

Не могу понять что считаеться хорошим стилем: делать Rest запросы в контроллере или же в сервисе?

Comment: хорошим стилем будет действовать в соответствии с SOLID, GRASP. В идеале вынести логику обращения на стороннюю API в отдельный класс/классы. Но боюсь, что в этом случае вы просто не сможете это реализовать надлежащим образом. посему, если вызовы единичные, то оставьте их в сервисе, если их много попробуйте отказаться от рест темплейт и посмотреть на что-то вроде ретрофита. там совсем другой подход и вам будет проще правильно отделить логику сервиса от логики обращения к сторонней API

Comment: Контроллер принято оставлять максимально "тонким". Любая логика, в том числе запросы к удаленным сервисам, выносится в сервисный слой или слой модели.

Comment: @Bakuard, спасибо! Ещё вопрос, а можно ли интерфейс Model передавать в параметры сервисных методов, или это тоже плохой стиль? Или лучше в контроллере в addAttribute() передавать сервисный метод в параметры?